# Two Webpack Configs (Client, Server) Express App not hosting HTML files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, webpack

I am building an Application that has a Node Backend that I am trying to bundle with Webpack.

At first I had one Webpack configuration that had `target: node`. I was unable to compile Websockets into the frontend bundle unless I changed it to `target: web` but that wasn't compiling my backend code changes. I would have to run `tsc && webpack`.

I am now to two configs to compile them separately. My current config is:

```
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var fs = require("fs");

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
  .filter(function(x) {
    return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
  });

const common = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{ loader: "html-loader" }]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  }
};

const frontend = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  target: "web",
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"
        ),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/vendor")
      },
      {
        from: path.resolve(
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"
        ),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/vendor")
      }
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Flop The World Poker",
      template: "build/index.template.html"
    })
  ]
};

const backend = {
  entry: "./src/server.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "server.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  target: "node",
  externals: nodeModules
};

module.exports = [
  Object.assign({}, common, frontend),
  Object.assign({}, common, backend)
];
```

Before I switch to two configs I was able to host my `index.html` that is in my output folder using:

```js
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { listen } from "socket.io";
import { DeckController} from "./controllers";

const app: express.Application = express();
const port: number = ((process.env.PORT as any) as number) || 3000;

const server = createServer(app);
const io = listen(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static("static"));
app.use("/deck", DeckController);
app.use(express.static(__dirname, { extensions: ["html"] }));

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("Client connected..");

  socket.on("join", data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I am now receiving `cannot get /`. I can set up a route like

```
router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});
```

and receive `Hello World` in the browser.

Can anyone help me to figure out what changed that now I cannot host my html file?

Comment: u may try std boilerplate below:

Comment: const app = express(),
            DIST_DIR = __dirname,
            HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html')

app.use(express.static('./'));

Comment: @RobertRowntree Doesn't seem to work. Not sure the proper way to use the HTML_File variable. but I tried `app.get("*", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(HTML_FILE); });` and I get that the path needs to be Absolute error in the browser

Comment: I got this to work by setting the root when sending the file to by build folder

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with help from Robert in the comments. Here are my new files:

```
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var fs = require("fs");

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
  .filter(function(x) {
    return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
  });

const common = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  }
};

const frontend = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  target: "web",
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"
        ),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/vendor")
      },
      {
        from: path.resolve(
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"
        ),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/vendor")
      }
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Flop The World Poker",
      template: "build/index.template.html"
    })
  ]
};

const backend = {
  entry: "./src/server.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "server.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  target: "node",
  externals: nodeModules
};

module.exports = [
  Object.assign({}, common, frontend),
  Object.assign({}, common, backend)
];
```

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { listen } from "socket.io";
import { DeckController } from "./controllers";

const app: express.Application = express();
const port: number = ((process.env.PORT as any) as number) || 3000;

const server = createServer(app);
const io = listen(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static("./build"));
app.use("/deck", DeckController);
app.use(express.static(__dirname, { extensions: ["html"] }));

server.listen(port, () => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("Client connected..");

  socket.send("Testing Message");

  socket.on("join", data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```